# Quicker with SQL to SUM 0 values or exclude them?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to SUM a lot of rows.

Is it quicker (or better practice, etc) to do Option A or Option B?

**Option A**

```
SELECT
    [Person]
    SUM([Value]) AS Total
FROM
    Database
WHERE
    [Value] > 0
GROUP BY
    [Person]
```

**Option B**

```
SELECT
    [Person]
    SUM([Value]) AS Total
FROM
    Database
GROUP BY
    [Person]
```

So if I have, for Person X:

```
0, 7, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 9, 0, 0
```

Option A does:

```
a) Remove zeros
b) 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 9
```

Option B does:

```
a) 0 + 7 + 0 + 6 + 0 + 5 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 4 + 0 + 9 + 0 + 0
```

Option A has less summing, because it has fewer records to sum, because I've excluded the load that have a zero value.  But Option B doesn't need a WHERE clause.

Anyone got an idea as to whether either of these are significantly quicker/better than the other?  Or is it just something that doesn't matter either way?

Thanks :-)

Comment: I'd say write easy code - easy to write and easy to read, and easy to maintain. Let the dbms optimizer take care of performance tricks.

Comment: If you have a lot of rows to sum then test on your rows.   Best practice is clear code.  That code is not even equivalent.

Comment: Thanks :-)   I should probably have added that (a) I know that [Value] is always positive, and (b) I'm later going to Join/Filter this to something else that means I don't mind whether people are on the list with 0, or not on the list at all.  What I actually need is a Sum of [Value] for each person who has a positive sum.  So it's a good point that these aren't the same in theory, but in my particular practice, they give me the same information, so my only choice as to best approach was which is quicker or better practice ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, *if you have a filtered index that exactly matches the `where` clause*, and if that index removes a significant amount of data (as in: a good chunk of the data is zeros), then definitely the first... If you *don't* have such an index: then you'll need to test it *on your specific data*, but I would probably expect the unfiltered scenario to be *faster*, as it can do use a range of tricks to do the sum if it doesn't need to do branching etc.

However, the two examples aren't functionally equivalent at the moment (the second includes *negative* values, the first doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Value` is always positive the 2nd query might still return less rows if there's a `Person` with all zeroes.

Otherwise you should simply test actual runtime/CPU on a really large amount of rows.

Comment: "Otherwise you should simply test actual runtime/CPU on an amount of rows that represents your expected data volume and distribution" - FTFY ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell: That's a good translation :)  There are just many developers who test on a small subset of the actual data and then wonder why it's different on production. Btw, the latest answer compared estimated plans on 7 rows :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36444902/quicker-with-sql-to-sum-0-values-or-exclude-them/36445303#36445303

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, the two are not functionally equivalent. In addition to the differences already pointed out (negative values, different output row count), Option B also filters out rows where Value is NULL. Option A doesn't.

Comment: Thanks (not really an 'answer', but a useful comment)  :-) I should probably have added that (a) I know that [Value] is always positive, and (b) I'm later going to Join/Filter this to something else that means I don't mind whether people are on the list with 0, or not on the list at all. What I actually need is a Sum of [Value] for each person who has a positive sum. So it's a good point that these aren't the same in theory, but in my particular practice, they give me the same information, so my only choice as to best approach was which is quicker or better practice ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Execution plan for both of these and using a small dataset similar to the one you provided, Option B is slightly faster with an Estimated Subtree Cost of .0146636 vs .0146655. However, you may get different results depending on the query or size of dataset. Only option is to test and see for yourself.

http://www.developer.com/db/how-to-interpret-query-execution-plan-operators.html

```
Drop Table #Test
Create Table #Test (Person nvarchar(200), Value int)
Insert Into #Test
Select 'Todd', 12 Union
Select 'Todd', 11 Union
Select 'Peter', 20 Union
Select 'Peter', 29 Union
Select 'Griff', 10 Union
Select 'Griff', 0 Union
Select 'Peter', 0 Union


SELECT [Person], SUM([Value]) AS Total
FROM #Test
WHERE [Value] > 0
GROUP BY [Person]

SELECT [Person],SUM([Value]) AS Total
FROM #Test
GROUP BY [Person]
```

Comment: @dnoeth I understand. I wouldn't expect this to change much based on the dataset they provided. However, they can test the Execution plan for a larger set on their own. I tested up to a couple thousand rows and it still shows Option B as the winner. A much large set may be different as you stated.

Comment: Numbers from an estimated plan are useless, you must compare the actual runtime/CPU/IO.

Comment: @dnoeth how are you testing actual runtime/CPU/IO to determine the "winner" query? Happy to confirm using your method and would also like to understand why the estimated subtree cost from "including actual execution plan" on SQL Server is useless? Thanks for the comments and any advice.

Comment: Estimated rows might be totally wrong (after WHERE/JOIN) and the optimizer doesn't now about the actual CPU usage of a function/calculation. A simple way to get the overall numbers is `SET STATISTICS TIME` & `SET STATISTICS IO` or using sys.dm_exec_query_stats` or a 3rd party tool like http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks. I will check this out and see how it goes. Appreciate the feedback.